# Astrodin parametric equation derivation

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, definite-integrals

I know, that the astroid with equation
$$
x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}=a^\frac{2}{3}
$$
can be parametricly expressed as:
$$
x=a*cos^3(t)
$$

$$
y=a*sin^3(t).
$$

I was wandering if there is a way, to derive parametric equations from formula at the top.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the kind of parametrisation you want?

Comment: Whenever you have an equation $u^2+v^2=c^2$ with $c> 0$, you can write $u = c \cos(t)$ and $v = c \sin(t)$.  In this case $u = x^{1/3}$, $v = y^{1/3}$ and $c = a^{1/3}$.

Comment: @Vid: You did it already. Is there a question?

Comment: Not related to the parametrisation, but i think the graph is quite pretty : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rkg0ltsmvr

Comment: Ok, to make me clear... I knew the parametrisation from Wikipedia, but didn't know from where it comes... I am wandering if there is a general approach to find such a parametrisation or do ve have to guess it. But I think, that @Robert kinda gave me a way how to think about it.

Comment: @Vid its more of a 'generalised approach', than a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when we see the equation
$$x^m + y^m = a^m$$
we quickly think of the parameterization
$$x = a \cos^{2 /m} (\theta), ~ y = a \sin^{2/m} (\theta), ~ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$$
because it reminds us of the trigonometric identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$. In the above, we have chosen $x$ and $y$ such that $x^m = a^m \cos^2 \theta$, and $y^m = a^m \sin^2 \theta$.